# is there a way in OPL to maximize the minimun of a list of decision variables?

Tags: linear-programming, cplex, opl, simplex

I want to do something like this:

```
dvar Q [1..10];
maximize min(i in 1..10) Q[i] ;
```

Q has 10 different values which i don´t know, i want that the minimun of all those values be as high as possible

But this doesn´t allow me to use Q which is a desicion variable

Is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 0):

```
dvar int+ Q [1..10] in 0..20;
maximize min(i in 1..10) Q[i] ;
```

works fine